# flutter-firebase_auth- gradlew.bat exited abnormally

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, firebase-authentication

""I WAS TRYING TO CONNECT MY FLUTTER APP TO FIREBASE"

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\flutter\project\notification\flutterapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\flutter\project\notification\flutterapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\flutter\project\notification\flutterapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs due to older gradle version in project.

Solved the issue by updating Project level build.gradle under dependencies classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1' and gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/335#issuecomment-547273581